# Reset BIOS from Ubuntu

Tags: boot, bios, reset

I am on a Thomson NEO14 2 32SB

I need to reset the BIOS in order to enable GOP Driver. I have a black screen on startup until Ubuntu boots.

The thing is, I don't have a CMOS battery and neither a button to reset it.

I had tried this :

```
modprobe nvram
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nvram
```

But NVRAM does not exist.

Holding power down for 30 seconds doesn't work.
I am also unable to boot with a USB since I need to manually boot it from the BIOS.

Comment: **DANGER DANGER DANGER**. Don't **EVER EVER EVER** use **dd** if you don't know what it's going to do. You could have caused some unrecoverable damage had this worked. What is the "GOP" driver?

Comment: The "gop driver" is an Intel Embedded Graphics Drivers used for the main display